# Family of Lines

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need to draw a family of lines connecting (a,0) and (0,b), where a+b=2, and determine an equation for the envelope of this family of lines.  I need to do this in mathematica and don't know where to start.

Comment: You may find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Constructing_B.C3.A9zier_curves) interesting.  (This is the quadratic case.)

Answer (score 2):

The second part of your question can be resolved as follows. First find the equation for any given line. `y = k x + y0`.

```
Solve[{b == k * 0 + y0, 0 == k * a + y0, a + b == 2}, {k, y0, a}]
```

> `{{k -> b/(-2 + b), y0 -> b, a -> 2 - b}}`

It is clear enough, that the bottom and leftmost boundaries are the `x` and `y` axes. Let's find the boundary on top. We have determined, that any given line is described by an equation `y == b x / (b - 2) + b`. For a given `x` we need to find the maximum possible `y` under the constraints that `0 < b < 2`.

```
Maximize[{b + b x / (b - 2), 0 < b < 2}, b]
```

returns a pretty complicated result the third line of which we are interested in. It reads

> `2 - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x] + x` for `0 < x < 2`

and this code illustrates the result:

```
Plot[Evaluate@(Table[b + b x/(b - 2), {b, 0, 1.8, .2}]~
    Join~{2 - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x] + x}), {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Evaluate@(Table[Blue, {10}]~Join~{Directive[Thick, Black]}), AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: envelope]

Comment: Try adding `AspectRatio -> Automatic` to the plot, to make the axes equally scaled.

Comment: Fair enough, given the symmetry of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of your question (finding the envelope) we can use the argument from page 5 of [these lecture notes](http://student.plattsburgh.edu/quenelgt/talks/stringart.pdf).  Basically the envelope is where two very close strings intersect each other.  We can parameterize the string by:

$$
\{x,y\} = \{x_1(t),y_1(t)\}(1-s) + \{x_2(t),y_2(t)\}s
$$

Where the $\{x_i,y_i\}$ represent the two endpoints, $s\in [0,1]$ is an 'arclength' parameter that sweeps from one end of a string to another, and $t$ is the parameter that 'moves' the endpoints.  In your case:

$$
\begin{align}
\{x_1,y_1\} &= \{t,0\} \\
\{x_2,y_2\} &= \{0,2-t\}
\end{align}
$$

Describing the general case in Mathematica:

```
posn = {x1[t], y1[t]} (1 - s) + {x2[t], y2[t]} s
```

Finding the intersection:

```
soln = Solve[
        Thread[Equal @@ (posn/. {{s -> s1, t -> t1}, {s -> s2, t -> t2}})],
        {s1, s2}]
```

Next we need to take the limit as $t_2$ approaches $t_1$.  `Limit` has some trouble with this, so we can instead expand all of our functions to first order around `t1`:

```
envs = FullSimplify@
  Normal[First@soln /. 
    f : (x1 | x2 | y1 | y2) :> 
     Function[t, Evaluate@Series[f[t], {t, t1, 1}]]]
```

Finally we can substitute this back into `posn` to get a parametric solution:

```
envp = FullSimplify[posn /. (envs /. {s1 -> s, t1 -> t})]
```

This solution is a little unwieldy (but it shows that a solution exists for arbitrary differentiable $x_i$ and $y_i$!).  We can substitute your functions in:

```
envp /. {x1 -> (# &), y1 | x2 -> (0 &), y2 -> (2 - # &)}
(* {t^2/2, 1/2 (2 - t)^2} *)

ParametricPlot[%, {t, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
 Prolog -> {Gray, Line[Table[{{t, 0}, {0, 2 - t}}, {t, 0, 2, 0.1}]]}]
```

[image]

Note that if we rotate 45 degrees we can see this is the equation for a parabola:

```
Solve[Eliminate[Sqrt[2]{u, v} == RotationMatrix[45 Degree].%%, t], v]
(* {{v -> 1/2 (1 + u^2)}} *)
```

Comment: Where on earth did you come up with those beautiful lecture notes?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP [First result](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=string+art+envelope) (You just have to know the right keywords...)

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question can be done using `Plot`

```
f[a_, x_] := 2 - a - (2 - a) x/a 
Plot[Table[f[a, x], {a, .001, 2, .03}], {x, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

or `Graphics` with `Line` primitives:

```
Graphics[Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Line[{{a, 0}, {0, 2 - a}}]}, {a, 0, 2, .03}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: `Graphics` is probably the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a polynomial family, here is an algebraic approach:

```
family = x/a + y/b - 1 // Together // Numerator;
constraint = a + b - 2;
envsys = Flatten@{family, D[family, {{a, b}}] - λ D[constraint, {{a, b}}], constraint}
(*  {-a b + b x + a y, -b + y - λ, -a + x - λ, -2 + a + b}  *)

env = First@GroebnerBasis[envsys, {λ, a, b}]
(*  4 - 4 x + x^2 - 4 y - 2 x y + y^2  *)

ContourPlot[env == 0, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
 Prolog -> {Thin, Table[Line[{{a, 0}, {0, 2 - a}}], {a, 0, 2, 0.1}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also use `Eliminate` instead of `GroebnerBasis`.

```
env = Eliminate[Thread[envsys == 0], {λ, a, b}]
(*  -4 + 4 y - y^2 == x^2 + x (-4 - 2 y)  *)

ContourPlot[Evaluate@env, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```